# Steps navigation problem in Intellij idea with cucumber 4.6.0

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

I have changed cucumber-junit and cucumber-java8 version from 4.2.5 to 4.6.0 and now I can't navigate from feature file to step definitions classes.

How to reproduce:

1. Open feature file.
2. In feature file auto generate step definition.
3. You will get step and you are able to navigate to it using ctrl+mouse click.
4. Intellij idea adds deprecated dependency @cucumber.api.java.en.Given.
5. Change dependency to @io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
6. Navigation from point 3 is broken. It is not possible to navigate from feature file to step definitions file now.

Navigation from feature file to step definitions file works with deprecated annotations, so, I think I don't have problems with my project structure (I hope so :)).

Have anybody faced with such problem or it is some bug with Intellij idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please upvote [this ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391) for IDEA's Cucumber plugin to make it compatible with 4.5.0 annotations.